# Relation between exponential powered by imaginary number and trigonometry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

When I was trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$
\frac  {d^2x}{dt^2} + 4x = t^2
$$
I arrived to the following particular expression $x_h(t)$:
$$
x_h(t) = Ae^{2it} + Be^{-2it}
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary number;

The teacher set it directly to : $A\cos2t + B\sin2t$

While originally $e^{it} = \cos(it) + \sin(it)$

How he concluded that ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo4Up.jpg

Comment: You have mis-stated [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).  $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t} = \cos t + \mathrm{i} \sin t$.

Comment: is it $$x''=...$$ or is it $$ (x')^2=....$$

Comment: First one of course.

Comment: Then you mean $\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)^2 x$, not what you wrote.

Comment: Yes. Can you edit it ?

Comment: No.  Because I would change it to "x''", which Math.SE will reject as too short.  Why are you unable to click the "edit" link and make such a change?

Comment: It's corrected ...droidnation

Comment: I don't know how to type a function on Math.SE and I was on my phone anyway not on a computer so it was complicated. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $x_h(t) = \hat{A} \mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}t} + \hat{B} \mathrm{e}^{-2\mathrm{i}t}$, where we use hats because these constants aren't going to be as useful so we will replace them shortly.  Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), 
$$  x_h(t) = \hat{A} (\cos(2t) + \mathrm{i}\sin(2t)) + \hat{B} (\cos(-2t) + \mathrm{i}\sin(-2t))  $$
and we immediately apply the [even-odd properties of sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Reflections), to get \begin{align*}
x_h(t) &= \hat{A} (\cos(2t) + \mathrm{i}\sin(2t)) + \hat{B} (\cos(2t) - \mathrm{i}\sin(2t))  \\
&= (\hat{A} +\hat{B}) \cos(2t) + (\hat{A} - \hat{B}) \mathrm{i}\sin(2t)  \text{,}  
\end{align*}
where we have collected by sines and cosines.

Since $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are arbitrary (complex) constants, so are $(\hat{A} +\hat{B})$ and $(\hat{A} - \hat{B})\mathrm{i}$.  You should recognize that this is a pair of independent constants.  (
$$  \begin{pmatrix} \hat{A} +\hat{B} \\ (\hat{A} -\hat{B})\mathrm{i} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \mathrm{i} & -\mathrm{i} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \hat{A}  \\ \hat{B} \end{pmatrix}  $$ and the determinant of that matrix is not zero.)  So we can replace them with symbols for different arbitrary constants : 
$$ x_h(t) = A \cos(2t) + B \sin(2t)  \text{.}  $$

Other than allowing us to carefully discriminate between the "before matrix multiplication" and "after matrix multiplication" completely arbitrary constants, the hats didn't do anything useful.  There is a semantic error going from "$x_h(t) = A \mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}t} + B \mathrm{e}^{-2\mathrm{i}t}$" to "$ x_h(t) = A \cos(2t) + B \sin(2t)$" because the first $A,B$ do not generally have the same values as the second $A,B$, *but*, it is widespread practice to not be too concerned about the details of arbitrary constants until they actually need values (for instance, to match an initial condition or a boundary condition).  When you see that re-use of $A$ and $B$ you are supposed to understand that "this $A$ and $B$" are not numerically the same as "that $A$ and $B$", but so far they're both arbitrary, so this is largely a distinction without a difference at the level of abstraction at which we are solving differential equations; arbitrary constants are *arbitrary*.

Comment: Sorry. After the matrix part, can you add more calculation, I didn't understand why the complex part was removed or replaced by sin2t

Comment: @droidnation : Is $\mathrm{i}$ a constant?  What happens when you multiple a constant by an arbitrary constant?  (There is no calculation in this idea.)

Comment: i is the imaginary number of the complex term.

Comment: @droidnation : So, is $\mathrm{i}$ *constant*?  (That is, your reply is not responsive to the two rhetorical questions.)